# Route to URL helper default parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using the code found here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-prefixing-in-routes-for-localization to prefix my routes with a locale.

```
Route::prefix('{lang?}')->middleware('locale')->group(function() {

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('index');
    })->name('index');
});
```

This locale is optional, but then my question is how am I supposed to reinject the locale when calling the `route` helper.

```
route('index');
```

to generate: `/it/` or `/`, or another, depending on the current locale.

If have tried this with no success :

```
Route::resourceParameters(['lang' => 'en']);
```

Comment: Did you call `Route::resourceParameters` in service provider?

Comment: No, right after the routes declaration.

Comment: why would `Route::resourceParameters` method be involved with this?

Comment: @lagbox Well I don't know what this field means so I tried since it felt loosely related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should should be,

```
route('index', ['lang' => 'fr']);
```

And change route helper with

```
/**
     * Generate a URL to a named route.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @param  array   $parameters
     * @param  bool    $absolute
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Route  $route
     * @return string
     */
    function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true, $route = null)
   {
    if (!isset($parameters['lang'])) $parameters['lang'] = App::getLocale();

        return app('url')->route($name, $parameters, $absolute, $route);
    }
```

Refer [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/example-on-how-to-use-multiple-locales-in-your-laravel-5-website?page=2) for more details.

Comment: I was expecting from something cleaner but thanks, it should work !

Comment: For some reason I have some error about redeclaring route() only when running my unit tests ... If you have any idea. (I have set the loading of the helpers in the bootstrap files)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I'm a bit unsure about what the question is. I took it as a way to generate URL without setting its dynamic parameters using `route` helper based on @rahulsm's answer.

So, I just figured out that you can set default parameters to `UrlGenerator` class. By listening on container `url` and `request` rebind event, it's possible to set default parameters there.

Inside `AppServiceProvider` boot

```
$this->app->rebinding('url', function ($url, $app) {
    $url->defaults(['lang' => $app->getLocale()]);
});
$this->app->rebinding('request', function ($app) {
    $app['url']->defaults(['lang' => $app->getLocale()]);
});
```

And then tried to call it,

```
route('index') // http://test.dev/en (based on config)
route('index', ['lang' => 'what']) //http://test.dev/what
```

This was tested only on Laravel 5.5, but I'm sure would also working on Laravel 5.4.

---

To explain a bit more about `rebinding` method available Laravel container<sup>[1]</sup>, firstly it's good to know how is Laravel [request lifecycle](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/lifecycle) works. In a one line simplified words, it should be the same as how an application in general works, which is: *receive a request, do the logic, return a response*.

At the second part, appear stage commonly said as bootstrapping, which one of its logic is try to store (register) classes (services) that mostly are important for the application<sup>[2]</sup> to work. Into a container. Thus, intended to be shared or even just for easily to be called, whether for the high-end developers or the framework itself.

Once registered, it will then be booted. This booting process has several actions to call<sup>[3]</sup>. One of it that suit this case is [firing (local) events](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Container/Container.html#method_rebound). Once a service has been resolved, it will try to call all registered rebound functions (listeners) at this stage. I can only assume this purpose is to make the application can be "easily mutate" the currently-resolving instance (service). Thus, defining `rebinding` method to listen to recalled event is the way to go.

Since Laravel allows to re-resolve (re-instantiate) a service, which means our previous stored value in the class is lost<sup>[4]</sup>, waiting it to be resolved (which then the listener called) is much make sense, right?

Back to `rebinding` snippet above, I used to listen to both `url` and `request` rebound services because `url` is [`request`'s dependent](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Routing/RoutingServiceProvider.php#L62). It waits for `request` service to be fully resolved and then call `setRequest`<sup>[5]</sup> method which flushes the needed instance which is `Illuminate\Routing\RouteUrlGenerator` that holds default parameter.

And as the name implies, `defaults`, used to set the default named parameters used by the URL generator<sup>[6]</sup>.

---

cit

<sup>[1] Container here refer to both `Illuminate\Foundation\Application` also `Illuminate\Container\Container`</sup>

<sup>[2] configure error handling, configure logging, detect the application environment</sup>

<sup>[3] resolving type-hinted dependencies, storing/caching stuffs to buffer, etc</sup>

<sup>[4] Unless retained like stored in class' static property</sup>

<sup>[5] [`Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator@setRequest`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L559)</sup>

<sup>[6] `Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator`, either calling `URL::route('route.name')`, `url('your-url')`, `app('url')->route('route.name')`, or `route('route.name')`, they refer to the same class</sup>

Comment: It seems cleaner than the other solution but I didn't really get exactly the usage of the rebinding and defaults methods (I did look at the doc and source code comment). Could you explain for future readers?

Comment: A lot cleaner indeed. But, I suggest you to not using kind of "global modifier" like this at the first place. Since, let's say, 3 months later, you'll forgot and regret for what you've made. I'll try to write it more when ready.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed explanations, very enlightning. It didn't work fully on my case and I used the first solution so I accepted this one.

Comment: Yeah, I can see it indirectly, this kind is actually better for a fresh apps. Lower-level approach like modifying PHP `$_SERVER` global variable in `index.php` for instance, is also more suitable for fresh apps installation.